# How to repair .zip files?

Tags: macos, terminal, zip, file-corruption, repair

To begin with, I don't know a single thing about coding, computers, etc. It'd be nice of computer masters if my question could be answered in detail (ex: type this in, screenshot, if possible).

First of all, I received several .zip files on my MacBook Air. I don't even know what kind, but the whole thing is around 31.5 cm wide and 23 cm long.

I think the .zip files contain .img files, probably more than 4000. The reason behind this huge file is because we're making an album of a bunch of pictures. However, I'm not sure if these images are screenshots or .gifs.

For some reason, the files that I receive look like images to me, but the extension sometimes says .gif instead of .img.

Now, when I try to open the .zip files, a notice that reads:

> Cannot read archive data.

to which I usually press 'Ignore All' or 'Stop'.

Since 'Stop' is highlighted in blue, it looks promising. I press on it, and it says:

> Cannot read archive data.

The same thing happens when I press on 'Ignore All'.

I tried to look for a solution already, to which this one website told me to use something called Terminal. (The .zip file's name is memories.)

I assumed that the .zip files were corrupted, so (as the website told me) I entered:

```
zip
(enter)
-F memories.zip --out please.zip
```

This didn't work. This showed up:

```
Fix archive (-F) - assume mostly intact archive
    zip warning: No .zip file found
        (If all you have are splits (.z01, .z02, ...) and no .zip, try -FF)
zip I/O error: No such file or directory
zip error: File not found or no read permission (memories.zip)
```

I tried the following:

```
-FF memories.zip --out please.zip
```

Still didn't work. This showed up:

```
Fix archive (-FF) - salvage what can
    zip warning: could not open input archive: memories.zip
Scanning for entries...

Could not find:
  memories.z01

Hit c      (change path to where this split file is)
    s      (skip this split)
    q      (abort archive - quit)
    e      (end this archive - no more splits)
    z      (look for .zip split - the last split)
 or ENTER  (try reading this split again):
```

I stopped here, as I didn't have a clue what to do next. Can someone please help me...?

Comment: Some points: zip files don't have dimensions in centimetres, so that part is utterly confusing. An .img file is not a picture, it's a "drive image" [like .dmg] & long obsolete on macOS. Try something other than the macOS Unarchiver - maybe [Stuffit Expander](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/stuffit-expander-16/id919269455?mt=12) freeware, which is capable of more formats than the native structure.

Comment: A screenshot can be a .GIF file. https://www.keka.io/en/ is another ZIP-compatible archiver-extractor app available in the App Store. Its Help section for extracting files from a ZIP archive is at https://github.com/aonez/Keka/wiki/Extracting-with-Keka . However, please consider the archives you were provided may have been corrupted before you got them, and you may need to ask for a freshly made set of ZIP files to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the person who zipped the files up decided to split them into
parts in order to have reasonable-sized files, and you have not downloaded
the `.zip` file or not all the other parts/splits.

The Winzip article
[Splitting Zip files](http://kb.winzip.com/help/help_splitdlg.htm)
says:

> Each of the segments of the split Zip file will have a different extension. WinZip creates files with names like Data.z01 or Data.zx01, Data.z02 or Data.zx02, and so on, except for the very last segment of the new Zip file. The last segment will always have either the .zip or .zipx extension, respectively, based on the compression method used when creating the Zip file (e.g., Data.zip, Documents.zipx).
>
> To open the split Zip file, open the file with the .zip or .zipx extension. Don't try to open any of the files with the numbered extensions; WinZip won't recognize them as Zip files.
>
> Once the split Zip file has been opened, you can work with it much as you would work with a regular Zip file, except you can't add any new files or remove existing files. Some operations such as creating self-extracting Zip files and editing comments are also disabled for split Zip files.

From the errors you are getting, it seems that you have downloaded some splits,
but not the main `.zip` file.
You should get that file, and check also that you have all the splits.